# VS Code v.1.31: Pytorch auto-filling issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytorch

VS Code v.1.31: Doesn't work auto-filling for "torch." class like: torch.randn() etc. Showed "No such module error". Although everything executes just fine without any issues. Is there any solution to fix the error without disabling it to be displayed in future? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Most of those issues are fixed in Pytorch v1.0.1. Intellisense may not be showing suggestions for functions like torch.randn if Jedi language server is being used (Please check this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1098) for more details). 
Open settings.json and set "python.jediEnabled" to False. You will be prompted to reload VSCode. Once this is done, it will download Language Server and the issue will be fixed.

[image: torch.randn suggestions working.]